# How to find the origin of an Attribute from ISymbol

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, custom-attributes, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm currently developing a [DiagnosticAnalyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.diagnostics.diagnosticanalyzer) to warn users if they try to use anything tagged with a custom `Attribute`.

Let's say I have an `Attribute` `Experimental` and declare a field

```
[Experimental]
Thing myThing;
```

then try to use it somewhere

```
myThing.MethodOnThing()
```

If I register onto `SyntaxKind.InvocationExpression` in my analyzer, I am able to catch this use of `myThing` and add a warning. However, the `ISymbol`'s name will be `MethodOnThing`. Therefore, my warning will say something like "MethodOnThing is marked Experimental..." when I would like it to say "myThing is marked Experimental".

I am getting the attributes on the symbol like this

```
var symbol = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(context.Node, context.CancellationToken).Symbol;
var attrs = symbol.GetAttributes();
```

I'd like to know if there's a precise way to access the source of the `Experimental` attribute (`myThing`) when I'm currently looking at an invocation of a method.

Comment: If you know that symbol is `IMethodSymbol` and want to get attributes for it receiver, just do it: `symbol.ReceiverType.GetAttributes()`

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria this almost works, however, if I set my attribute on a variable I won't get the variable name, just the variable's type name.

Comment: On the one hand, you can get a left hand of `InvocationSyntaxNode` and retrieve symbol for it. So you wil get a name from `ISymbol` and can get a type if symbol is `ILocalSymbol`, `IParameterSymbol`, `IPropertySymbol` and so on. Hovewer, what you want to show onto this case: `GetThing().MethodOnThing()` when type `Thing` is tagged with your custom attribute? On the other hand, you may try to retreive `IOperation` for the corresponding nodes and it can give you more usefull info, but it's expensive.

Comment: In your example, there is no `[Experimental]` attribute on `MethodOnThing`, so why would you want to report that there is one? Instead, there is one on `myThing`, so I suppose you should analyze `IdentifierNameSyntax` nodes.

Comment: Agreed with Kris. You probably should analyze IdentifierNameSyntax, retrieve it's ISymbol and then analyze its attributes.